# Memory optimization for generating data larger than RAM

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, optimization, python-itertools

Let say I want to generate the Cartesian product of a range, ie:

```
from itertools import product
var_range = range(-10000, 10000)
vars = list(product(var_range, repeat=2))
var[:10]
```

So the output is like:

```
[(0, 0),
 (0, 1),
 (0, 2),
 (0, 3),
 (0, 4),
 (0, 5),
 (0, 6),
 (0, 7),
 (0, 8),
 (0, 9)]
```

However, this seems to much for mu RAM and my IPython (12GB RAM) crashes.

I was thinking on spiting the ranges to batches and use it in fours loop iterations:

> [-10000,-5000],[-4999,0],[1,5000],[5001,10000]

Then, after each iteration I could save it as pandas dataframe to h5 file and than append to the previous iteration outcome.

I have also read about generators in python.

- If so, then HOW in this case, generators could bring optimisation?
- What would be the most pythonic way to optimise such simple case?

Comment: `product(var_range, repeat=2)` is already an iterator. Just don't make it into a list.

Comment: I would use `numpy` for such operations.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ok, how would you suggest to move it straight to the h5 then in batches? (because I assume that is what you have in mind)

Comment: @sardok Could you please provide code for what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would work:

```
from itertools import product
var_range = range(-10000, 10000)
vars = product(var_range, repeat=2)
print([next(vars) for _ in range(10)])
```

Converting non-`list` types to `list` takes a long time, especially with this long sequence, instead you could just use part of it, the first ten elements, then it should work, as you do with `list(...)`, it processes the whole object, while `next` ten times doesn't.

Comment: Ok, this generates only 10 elements. So basically to cover entire range I would have to put this inside a loop. I need to put ALL of the generated values to a file. So we are back to the  loop then with the last line as the body of the loop. Is there any other *non-loop* idea to save  the entire range to a file using this generator?

Comment: I mean the goal is the 10k x10k tuples here.

Comment: @mCs Well than make it clearer, you showed that you wanted the first ten and i gave the solution to you.

Comment: Yes, because 10 was easier to show in question than 10k ;) I vote up your answer.